# Jobs run despite workflow rules

Tags: yaml, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I did set up a CI on a GitLab (version 15.7.0), and I'm trying to run a pipeline **only** if a commit has been made on `master` branch, first.

The pipeline should only run only when a commit is made on master branch, but It's not. It runs for any commit pushed to any branch.

That's what I put in the `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
default:
  image: python:3

  cache:
    paths:
      - ".cache/pip"

workflow:
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master" # Also tried with $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
        when: always

stages:
  - prerequisites
  - pytest

variables:
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"

prerequisites:
  stage: prerequisites
  needs: []
  script:
    - python --version
    - pip install pytest

pytest:
  stage: pytest
  needs: ["prerequisites"]
  script:
    - python -m pytest -v tests/
```

I assumed I don't have to specify `- when: never` to cover other cases because the documentation states:

> pipelines do ***not*** run in any other case.
>
> - [Ref](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/workflow.html#workflow-rules-examples)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, **quotes** around your condition **are important**!

It should be:

```yaml
workflow:
    rules:
      - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
        when: always
```

It's weird because quotes are inconsistent in GitLab docs, they're here in one section, but disappear in another. Anyway, add quotes, don't ask questions.